# Angular custom directive not working in 1.3.0

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7LRDS/774/)

This fiddle works with `angular **1.1.3**`. But not working with `1.3.0`

Comment: Give reason if you dont understand question. Instead of down voting

Comment: See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Migrating from Previous Versions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrating-from-1-2-to-1-3).

Comment: **DON'T:** Tell us "it doesn't work" and leave it at that.
We can figure this out by the fact that you've asked the question in the first place, and without further information, we will close it for being unclear.

Comment: Hey Mr Bihani. With newer versions of angular, you can use `"<div ng-transclude-replace>Here2</div>"`. With that said, please think of StackOverflow as a database of useful questions and answers for anyone to use, and consider how useful your title, links and problem-description are. You didn't even include "transclude" in your problem description which is the obvious keyword here and your jsfiddle is likely to be gone in a year.

Comment: have checked my fiddle ? or someone else's ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register your controller with your module using:

```
myApp.controller('test', test);
```

That'll fix it, but you really ought to look at some recent angular documentation, if you're migrating from version 1.1.x. It's a very old version and a lot has changed since (we're currently at version 1.6 right now).

## Update

It seems you may be misunderstanding how transclusion works. When you use `ng-transclude`, everything inside the element you put it on in your template, is replaced by whatever is inside the element you use your directive on. So in this case, `Here2` get's replaced by `Here1`. What you probably want in this case, is something like this:

```
myApp.directive('userForm', function() {
    return {
        transclude :true,
        template: '<div>Here2 <span ng-transclude></span></div>'
    };
});
```

Comment: that doesnt worked

Comment: Here's [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e50rwbp7/) with my change, using Angular 1.3, working just fine.

Comment: i have updated fiddle. Please check

Comment: You're still not registering your controller, which causes an exception to be thrown.

Comment: are you looking at http://jsfiddle.net/7LRDS/774/  this one ?

Comment: Yes, I am. I change the angular version to 1.3.0 and add `myApp.controller("test", test);` and it still works perfectly fine. [Here's my update](http://jsfiddle.net/7LRDS/776/). Could you explain what it is supposed to be doing and how it goes wrong? Perhaps you're misunderstanding transclusion?

Comment: Maybe iam misunderstanding transclusion. I want here1 and here2 both get print like 1.1.3 in 1.3.0. What changes needs tobe done ? Please help

Comment: I have updated my answer with an example of how to make transclusion work like you want it to.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7LRDS/776/ This fiddle still printing  only here1. Please check

Comment: I only updated my answer above, here's an [updated fiddle with the same code](http://jsfiddle.net/7LRDS/777/).